Why can I hear when my shower gets hot?
I noticed recently that when I turn on my shower, I can hear the moment that the water heats up. The hissing sound gets slightly louder and its pitch changes. The pressure doesn't noticeably change during this time (and I can't see why it would), so this is a bit of a puzzle. In fact, in many places I've lived I've had a sense of when the shower water got hot, but I never consciously noticed what the cue was until a few weeks ago.
Apologies if this turns out to be more of a plumbing question rather than a physics question, but without knowing the answer it's impossible to tell ahead of time.
Edit: The hissing sound I'm referring to appears to come from the shower head.

Yes, it's likely a plumbing problem. I'm not a plumber but I'd guess that it's just the pipe carrying hot water sounds different than the pipe carrying cold water.

@stickynotememo, that's not how plumbing works though. When you turn the hot water on in a shower, water flows through the same pipes at all times. It's just that at first, much of the water in the pipes is cold, and you need to flow that out so that recently heated water from the heater can reach the shower head. Secondly, the hissing sound I'm referring to comes from the shower head, not the pipes. I'll update the question to mention this.

The "hissing" most likely is the sound of turbulence downstream of some restriction. All new shower heads sold here in the U.S.A. are designed to restrict the flow to some number of gallons per minute  so that people living in certain very dry places can take long showers without seriously impacting their neighbors. Of course the control valve also is a restriction.

IDK why the sound of the turbulence would change, but maybe it's related to the fact that the density of the hot water is less than the density of the cold.

Have you tried replacing the shower head and see if you get a similar effect? Happily that would be a good thing to do both scientifically (get more information on the phenomenon) and practically (if there's an obstruction in the shower head replacing it might get rid of the sound).

Hot water in general sounds different from cold water. Cold water poured out of a kettle sounds different than hot water poured out of the same kettle, etc. etc.

The speed of sound in water increases with temperature.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312478/frequency-difference-when-water-splashes-at-different-temperatures
